# Does Eclipse or Android usually pull in other code?

Tags: android, eclipse

So, we were coding an Android application in Eclipse, and we couldn't figure out why a class wouldn't delete. We removed it from the application completely, and it was still there. Then we found out that it was actually pulling in the information from another application. Does this usually happen?

EDIT: More information:

The problem only happened when we built on 1 of the three devices, the one that had the App it was pulling information from. On the other 2, it wouldn't run at all. The other App had a different name, signing key, and was a different project.

EDIT 2: It happened again. There is an app called SMS.apk, and the second is called 2012.apk. The class names are different, and the project names are different. There are no references to eachother in the files at all. But it was pulling in code from SMS to 2012. It worked, until we removed SMS, when we realized that it was using that code. At this point, we are a little worried we accidentally stumbled upon Skynet.

Comment: Not enough information to help. By default, Eclipse won't "pull in" source without a reason to do so.

Comment: was this other application included as an external JAR file?

Comment: As a side note: The app was a newer version of the old one it was 'pulling' the class from. So, the class names were the same. Once we deleted the old app, the new one no longer functioned. Both apps were deployed with different signing keys.

Comment: On the other 2 devices, it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Eclipse does not do that. The reason this is happening is most likely because its an SMS app, so you're using broadcast receiver. Heres a tidbit from a helpful book:

> One interesting characteristic of the BroadcastReceiver is that you
>   can continue to listen for incoming  SMS messages even if the
>   application is not running; as long as the application is installed on
>   the device,  any incoming SMS messages will be received by the
>   application

[Source.  pg. 273](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/sites/default/files/users/21/file/Chapter%208%209781118087299-2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this was freaking us out a bit.